# KVO addObserver to CoreData object's one-to-many relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, key-value-observing

Hi everyone years reading StackOverflow, now I decided to join. I am struggling to get this resolved:

I have a "Depot" entity that has two to-many relationships "Persons" and "Trucks". I want to observe when, given a "Depot" object, there are changes (insert,remove) in one of the relationships (and understand in which one).

Currently i am doing this:

`[mydepot addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"Trucks" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];`

and

`[mydepot addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"Persons" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];`

but everytime something changes in one of the two related collections, `observeValueForKeyPath` gets called twice (one time for each keypath).

Am i doing it wrong? Looking at "change" dict, (observing with also OptionOld) shows no unexpected changes (when i change persons, trucks is not changed) but the notification is still raised.

Thanks, Pietro

edit: it seems that both times the "change" dict contains the entire relationship in the "new" field. (obviously one time Persons and one time Trucks)

edit2:as it happens even bserving simple properties, could it be related to the managedctx save operation? as if when you save, the entire object is considered changed..

Answer (score 10):

In the Key Value Observing Programming Guide it says that

> If you're using Core Data, you can register the parent with the application's notification center as an observer of its managed object context. The parent should respond to relevant change notifications posted by the children in a manner similar to that for key-value observing.

That could effectively mean that the recommended practice is not to use `addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:`, but register for the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` instead.

Comment: Yeah this is my second choice, because i have just one object at a time that i want to observe (but multiple that can get modified in the background), i think that this is a waste of notifications as i get notified for all changed objects and must filter out the notfications

Comment: @Peterdeka this is still the best and correct answer. You should accept it.

Answer (score 3):

If you set trucks atomically (`something.trucks = newArray`) you will get a value set notification. Instead use addObject/removeObject on the mutable array returned by `[ something mutableArrayValueForKey:@"trucks" ]`.

You can also use/implement the KVO generated accessors `insertObjectIntoTrucks:` / `countOfTrucks` etc.

You should read the KVO documentation. Under "Indexed To-Many Relationship Compliance" and "Unordered To-Many Relationship Compliance" [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding).

Comment: +1 Agree. Think in terms of modifying the existing collection of values instead of replacing the entire collection with a different collection.

Comment: Thanks, yeah but Depot is a CoreData NSManagedObject  subclass so should already implement KVO compliant accessors. And i'm doing what you say, as a matter of facts i'm only adding a new truck entity to the relationship, never replacing/setting the entire set(relationship). This is why i can't understand. As if i observe for two keypaths for example "Trucks" and "sqmeters"(that's not a relationship), if "sqmeters" is modified, two notifications are triggered (also one for the "trucks" kpath)

Comment: Key paths can depend on one another...maybe that's what's happening? Otherwise you'll have to look elsewhere

Comment: The model is very simple so it looks like there's no relationship between them...Couldn't it be related to the managedcontext save operation? as if saving triggers the creation of new sets if they were modified(a sort fo reallocation of objects)?

Comment: Be advised that the object is being modified in the background on a different "scratchpad" mangedobjectcontext, and then changes are merged

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 2):

If you want do know when an item is added or removed from the to-many trucks relation, you need to do KVO on the count (somewhere in your view controller) like this:

`[self.depot addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"trucks.@count" options:0 context:nil];`

Comment: This is perfect. Can't believe it took four years to get a single upvote.

Answer (score 1):

I come with the same problem. And I'm still sticking in this problem.

But what I'm sure is that the reason of the first time it be called is you do something like `[Depot addPerson:person]` while the reason of the second time it be called is the MOC save action will post a `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` notification which let your observer think another modify just happen.

And what is worse in my problem is that because of the observer, I will lost some my modifications of core data.

This make me feel I'm so stupid for almost two days.

I'm thinking to use register `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` in @Mundi 's answer

And if anyone have a better way , please let me know ASAP

Answer (score 0):

I kept some caches around as properties of a NSManagedObject and needed to invalidate those.  I first looked into using KVO and listening to `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`.

The simplest solution for me was to implement the methods `– [NSManagedObject  didSave]` and `– [NSManagedObject didTurnIntoFault]` like this.

```
@interface BazClass ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray* sortedItems;    // sorted items cache
@end

@implementation BazClass

@dynamic items; // this is a to many relationship. i.e. NSOrderedSet
@synthesize sortedItems;

- (NSArray*)sortedItems
{
    if (!_sortedItems) {
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"foo" ascending:YES];
        _sortedItems = [self.items sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
    }
    return _sortedItems;
}

// didSave and didTurnIntoFault will delete the sorted items cache
- (void) didSave
{
    self.sortedItems = nil;
}

-(void) didTurnIntoFault
{
    self. sortedItems = nil;
}
```